# iAd Banner won't load correctly

Tags: ios, xcode, iad

I followed a youtube tutorial on how to implement shared iads banner in my app. I have 10 VC so this is why i choosed the shared iads via delegate. Whenever I launch the app (On device or simulator) the ad doesn't appear on the first view controller. If i switch to the 2nd VC, it will load and show correctly. Then if i decide to go to the 3rd VC or back to the 1st VC, the banner will be white and no ads will load (even if i wait or go to any other VC).
Maybe the tutorial i watched wasn't correctly written, i don't know to be honest. Here's the code used:

### AppDelegate.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) ADBannerView *UIiAD;
```

### AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{     
 _UIiAD = [[ADBannerView alloc] init];
return YES;
}
```

### ViewController.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) ADBannerView *UIiAD;
```

### ViewController.m

```
- (AppDelegate *) appdelegate {
return (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
}

-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
_UIiAD = [[self appdelegate] UIiAD];
_UIiAD.delegate = self;

if ((int)[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)
{
    [_UIiAD setFrame:CGRectMake(0,518,320,50)];
}
if ((int)[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 480)
{
    [_UIiAD setFrame:CGRectMake(0,430,320,50)];
}
if ((int)[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 667)
{
    [_UIiAD setFrame:CGRectMake(0,600,320,50)];
}
if ((int)[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 736)
{
    [_UIiAD setFrame:CGRectMake(0,660,320,50)];
}


[self.view addSubview:_UIiAD];
}

-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{

[_UIiAD removeFromSuperview];
_UIiAD.delegate = nil;
_UIiAD = nil;    
}

-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner{
NSLog(@"ads loaded");
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0];
[_UIiAD setAlpha:1];
[UIView commitAnimations];

self.fullscreen = [[RevMobAds session] fullscreen];
self.fullscreen.delegate = self;
[self.fullscreen loadAd];
}

-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error{
NSLog(@"ads not loaded");
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0];
[_UIiAD setAlpha:0];
[UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

### Conclusion

I tried adding a delay in the ViewWillAppear method but it did not work.
I placed the banner in the storyboard and made sure it was on 0 alpha.
No other answer on SO helped me so hopefully someone will be able to resolve this issue. Thanks!

Comment: You should take a look into storyboards and autoLayout to remove lines 3 to `bannerViewDidLoadAd`. Regarding the animation: remove it and use `.hidden` instead of the alpha value. To change a value without animation use something along the lines `UIView setAnimationsEnabled:BOOL];`. Maybe add a placeholder in the storyboard to figure out where to place the adBanner. Except that: i dont know how ads behave if they are not added to a view, what happens to their internal state, since I just use them in two seperate views inside my app.

Comment: Sweet, i removed the animation and now i don't get any white banner but on the first VC the ad still doesn't load... I waited 1 minute and nothing showed. I changed the storyboard banner alpha from 0 to 1 and still nothing.

Comment: does the `didFail` get called or just `didLoad`?

Comment: So i just did everything you mentioned in your first answer and it works now. Thank you! It appears on the first VC. Now my last question, if you don't mind me asking... I tried without internet connection so see if the banner would dissapear (using _UIiAd.hidden = yes;) and it didn't dissapear and i know that apple will reject my app if i can't make it dissapear. Any ideas about that?

Comment: set it to hidden by default in the storyboard or at the point were you create it in AppDelegate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To conclude my comments,

1. use storyboard auto layout to position the banner or use a placeholder to get the position of the later banner.
2. Remove the animations and replace them with `.hidden=true` and `=false`.
3. Set the adBanner to `hidden` in storyboard or at the point of your initialization.